# assuming $\frac {x}{y - 1} \leq \frac {a}{b - 1}$ is it always true that $ \frac {x}{y} \leq \frac {a}{b}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

assuming $\frac {x}{y - 1} \leq \frac {a}{b - 1}$ is it always true that $ \frac {x}{y} \leq \frac {a}{b}$?

you can assume that $x,y,a,b$ are all greater than $0$.

This seams like a true statement, and even pretty trivial one, but when i am trying to prove that i only get by the given inequality that:

$$x(b-1) \leq a(y-1) $$
$$ xb - x \leq ay - a$$

and im pretty much stuck here.
how can i prove that formally?

Comment: Be careful.  It is possible for $b, y > 0$ without $b - 1 > 0$ or $y - 1 > 0$.

Answer (score 4):

No, e.g. $\frac{5}{7} < \frac{3}{4}$, but $\frac{5}{8} > \frac{3}{5}$.